# Describing the data cleaning process

Tags: data-cleaning

The term "Data Cleaning" is used to describe outlier checking, date parsing, missing value imputation to structuring datasets (organizing data values within a dataset) to facilitate analysis.

The latter is commonly referred to as "***Data Tidying***" but what about the former? I have seen outlier checking, date parsing and missing value imputation referred to as "*soft processing*", however I wonder if this is a commonly used term.

If I describe a component of *data cleaning* as "**soft processing**" is it reasonable to assume that knowledgeable people will know that I am referring to outlier checking, date parsing and missing value imputation?

In the field of Data Science, is there a commonly accepted phrase or term that umbrellas *outlier checking, date parsing and missing value imputation*.

Comment: Validation, preprocessing...

Comment: @Emre is this an answer or a suggestion?

Comment: Yes. These are common terms; use what fits. Soft processing is not a clear or common term.

Comment: @Emre why not make it an answer?; as opposed to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not modifying anything you can call it *validation*. If you are, you can call it *preprocessing*.